A worldline from the perspective of another in special relativity
Suppose we have two worldlines $\mathbf{x}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbf{y}(\alpha)$ parameterised by $\alpha$. What does the first worldline look like in a frame moving along the second? Is the correct relationship
$\mathbf{z}'(\alpha) = A(\mathbf{v}) \mathbf{x}'(\alpha)$,
where $A(\mathbf{v})$ is the Lorentz transformation and $\mathbf{z}(\alpha)$ is the worldline $\mathbf{x}(\alpha)$ in the frame moving with $\mathbf{y}(\alpha)$? If so, why? It is not obvious that a derivative of the Lorentz transformation w.r.t. $\alpha$ should not appear.
Edit:
I am not sure what is unclear about the question, but here is some more information.
The velocity $\mathbf{v}$ in the above is the velocity associated with $\mathbf{y}(\alpha)$ and thus depends upon the parameter $\alpha$. Thus the Lorentz transformation $A(\mathbf{v})$ depends upon $\alpha$ and can be differentiated with respect to it. This derivative describes the rate of change of axes moving along $\mathbf{y}(\alpha)$.
I believe the equation above to be correct, but I would like to know how to derive it if it is. Here is the equation again,
$\mathbf{z}'(\alpha) = A(\mathbf{v}) \mathbf{x}'(\alpha)$.
I believe it is correct for two reasons. First, if the wordlines $\mathbf{x}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbf{y}(\alpha)$ are the same, integrating the equation gives the proper time associated with the wordline, which makes sense. Second, if $\mathbf{y}(\alpha)$ is a straight line, $\mathbf{v}$ is constant and we get from integrating
$\mathbf{z}(\alpha) - \mathbf{z}(0) = A(\mathbf{v}) (\mathbf{x}(\alpha) - \mathbf{x}(0))$,
which is obviously consistent with how one transforms between inertial frames.
The problem is that differentiating the equation immediately above w.r.t. $\alpha$ involves the derivative of $A(\mathbf{v})$ w.r.t. $\alpha$ if $\mathbf{v}$ changes along the worldline, hence my uncertainty about whether the equation at the beginning of the question is correct.
Second edit:
I work in theoretical chemistry, so I have only a rudimentary knowledge of special relativity, but I would like to understand Thomas precession better because it is relevant to the spin-orbit interaction. I supposed the question was easy, but judging by the lack of responses I guess it is hard, which is surprising.
My hope was that an answer to my question would allow me to look at a pure time worldline from the perspective of a helical worldine corresponding to uniform circular motion and thus observe Thomas precession / Wigner rotation. My understanding of the Wikipedia articles on Thomas precession and Wigner rotation is that they are both the result of the fact that the Lorentz transformation changes along a general worldline (i.e., that the $A(\mathbf{v})$ is a function of $\alpha$ because the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ is). To put it another way, the axes of the comoving frame change along the worldline.
That is fine. But it leaves me wondering how the change in a spacetime point in an inertial frame relates to the change in a non-inertial frame. It is not clear from what I have read how this is addressed in special relativity. To be clear, for an infinitesimal $d\alpha$, there is a change in the axes of the comoving frame and the coordinates. How is this related to the corresponding change in the inertial frame? I don't know how to answer this based on the rule for transforming between inertial frames (the Lorentz transformation).
Somebody in the comments suggested considering the Euclidean case, which as far as I can tell means considering the geometry of curves in 3D or plane curves. If I move along a plane curve and use the tangent vector and normal vector as a local basis, the displacement from myself to another point in the plane in my basis (1) is related to the displacement in a fixed basis (2) by a rotation. The derivatives of the coordinates in (1) and (2) are related by a rotation and the derivative of the rotation. I don't see yet how this helps me to answer my question.

You did the right thing by editing the question to complete it, and I see the question has now been reopened.

What does "a derivative of the Lorentz transformation w.r.t. $\alpha$'' mean?

Have you tried your method in a more familiar setting: two curves in Euclidean space?

For a Galilean transformation instead of Lorentz transformation, the equation is correct. Is this what you had in mind with two curves in Euclidean space?

I assumed the question I posted had a simple answer. How does one transform a wordline from an inertial frame to a non-inertial frame which is itself specified by a worldline in the inertial frame? It must be possible, and I suppose the general prescription for doing it involves a differential equation, but I can't see how to come up with the correct answer.
The comments the question has received so far suggest it is in fact hard, which is surprising to me as someone just learning special relativity. My hope was that an answer to this question would help me to understand Thomas precession.

A general strategy for such questions is to consider the Galilean case (as you did) [especially for physical interpretation] and the Euclidean case [especially for analogous geometrical interpretation]. The fact that the "Galilean transformations are simpler in the sense that absolute-time is preserved" suggests that it may be too simple. So, go on to the Euclidean case and consider two curves (say, an arc of a circle and a line that met at the origin). Try your construction with rotation-matrices instead of Lorentz transformations.

Sorry, but I don't understand what the Euclidean case means. The Galilean limit makes sense because it keeps the equation I wrote four-dimensional. The curves you describe do not involve time if I understood correctly. How should I use them to analyse the equation?

For the Euclidean case, the curves are parametrized by arc-length. Minkowski's notion of "proper time" is an analogue of arc-length. The 4-velocity is the analogue of the unit-tangent-vector to the curve.  The "spatial-velocity" v is the analogue of "slope" in Euclidean geometry. The Lorentz boost transformation is the analogue of a rotation in Euclidean geometry.

Indeed, this question is not very simple. The number one primary issue is that there is no standard definition of "a frame moving along the second". In other words, if Bob is inertial then "Bob's worldline" has a standard agreed-upon meaning. But if Bob is non-inertial then "Bob's worldline" has no standard agreed-upon meaning.
So, in principle your question is somewhat backwards. It is up to you to define what you mean by "a frame moving along the second". Only after you have defined what you mean by that does "What does the first worldline look like" have an answer.
A reference frame is a coordinate system, so in principle the only requirement is that it must be a smooth one-to-one mapping between an open subset of events in spacetime to an open subset of points in $\mathbb{R}^4$. In addition to that requirement there are a few desiderata. You would like for the worldline of $\mathbf{y}$ to have constant position, possibly the spatial origin, in $\mathbf{y}$'s reference frame. You would also like for the coordinate time $t$ in $\mathbf{y}$'s frame to match $\mathbf{y}$'s proper time $\alpha$ when evaluated on $\mathbf{y}(\alpha)$. Other desiderata are less important, but might include some reasonable relationship between the other coordinates and distances from $\mathbf{y}$.
There are some possible approaches that are available in the literature. One is Fermi coordinates. There is also the proper reference frame which is closely related. I personally do not favor either of these approaches. Although they work well for points close to the worldline of the accelerating observer, if they are extended too far they fail by not being one-to-one. In other words, they will map the same event in spacetime to two different coordinates.
This problem is explained by Dolby and Gull who offer the solution of radar coordinates. One advantage of radar coordinates is that they obey Einstein's second postulate, which no other approach does. This is not a requirement, but it may be a desideratum for some situations, and it certainly does make the spatial coordinates more meaningful in terms of distances. Minguzzi gives a closed form expression for the metric in terms of radar coordinates.
Once you have chosen one of the above approaches for defining $\mathbf{y}$'s reference frame (or devised your own), then the transformation for $\mathbf{x}$'s worldline follows.

Thank you very much for your detailed response. It seems though that others have already defined what they mean by a frame moving along a second when they talk of the spin of a particle as constant in its rest frame and precessing in the lab frame as a result of its acceleration. What choice has been made and how is it justified?

@TedBurgess The links I posted describe some of the choices that have been made in detail. There is no justification needed. They (and you) are free to make any choice for any reason or no reason. It is purely a matter of convention.

I don't quite understand that. The precession is something that can be measured and should be independent of the choice I make about the frame I use. However, the statement that the spin is fixed in one frame is obviously not true in every frame. To convert to the lab frame, I need to know exactly what choice has been made.

@TedBurgess as you said earlier “the spin of a particle as constant in its rest frame and precessing in the lab frame”. So it cannot be true that “The precession … should be independent of the choice I make about the frame I use”. The precession depends on the choice of frame and there simply is no standard choice. Of course, measurement results are frame independent, such as the frequency of the voltage detected by a given loop.

To know what choice a specific author has made you have to read what that specific author wrote. Unfortunately, many authors are sloppy and don’t clearly state the details of their choice

Let me phrase my question another way. In what frame is the spin fixed and how do I transform the spin from that frame to my lab frame? You seem to be saying that the 'frame in which the spin is fixed' depends arbitrarily on the author, which I can't make sense of.

@TedBurgess Sorry, I don't know what to tell you. You can use radar coordinates, Fermi coordinates, Born coordinates, rotating Cartesian coordinates, etc. All of them will have the spin fixed. Each is different and will have different transformations. The easiest specifically for rotation is Born coordinates. For details of the transformation for Born coordinates, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_coordinates

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I can give you a very simple physical description of how the rotation comes about and hopefully it will give you some insight for your investigations. My description is based on Wigner Rotation. This is closely related to Thomas rotation and is the infinitesimal rotation that results from two successive infinitesimal non-parallel Lorentz boosts. Thomas rotation is simply the sum of the all the infinitesimal Wigner rotations, after the object has completed a closed loop path and returned to its starting point.

The diagram above is borrowed from the Mathpages page on Thomas Precession where the precession of an object following a circular path is analysed as a series of infinitesimal non parallel boosts approximated by a many sided polygon.


In the above animations the left animation (or the first animation if you are reading this on a mobile phone) is the  point of view of an inertial observer at rest with the blue square (S). There are 4 thrusters attached to the vertices of the red square and In this reference frame they are all started simultaneously by a synchronising initiating signal from the centre of the red square. In this rest frame of blue the red square (S') is simply parallel transported by the simultaneously applied impulses at the vertices and there is no hint of rotation in this reference frame. It should be clear that a gyroscope in the red reference frame will not precess as a result of the purely linear acceleration in this reference frame.
The right hand side is the point of view of an observer (S'') that sees the first blue inertial reference frame (S) as moving from South to North. The axes of S'' are represented by the green 'cross hairs' which are seen as moving North to South in (S). The Key to the observed rotation is the the thruster do no start simultaneously in S''. The rear thrusters start first and in the absence of a counter torque from the the upper thrusters the red square stat rotating. When the upper thrusters eventually start they stop the rotation. It is the asymmetric application of impulses due to the relativity of simultaneity, that causes the rotation. I wrote this simulation in C# a while back and it perfectly reproduces the rotation predicted by the Thomas rotation formula:
$$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\gamma_u+\gamma_v+\gamma_w)^2}{(1+\gamma_u)(1+\gamma_v)(1+\gamma_w)} -1 \right),$$
where u is the vertical velocity of the blue reference frame (S) relative to the green reference frame (S''), v is the velocity of the red square (S'') relative to the blue reference frame (S) and w is the relativistic vector addition of the u and v and is effectively the final velocity of the red square relative to the the green reference frame. $\gamma$ is simply the relativistic gamma factor for the respective velocities as denoted by the subscripts.  Things to Note:

The formula is independent of acceleration, so the rotation is purely a function of the initial and final velocities.
The top right thruster turns off just as it passes the origin of the green reference frame in both the left and right animations, which if nothing else, shows the two animations in different reference frames do not contradict each other.
All the thrusters run for the same proper time and with the same proper acceleration but appear to stop at different times due to simultaneity effects and time dilation. For instant the thrusters at the rear in left hand animation stop first because in that reference frame they appear to accelerate faster than the leading thrusters, to maintain Born rigidity and so they appear to run for a shorter period.
The resultant Wigner rotation is in the opposite sense to the path direction. You can imagine taking successive right turns and you will have followed a clockwise path and the Wigner rotation will be anticlockwise in that case. The Spare Time Physicist did a good video on Wigner rotation, but unfortunately he gets the direction of the rotation wrong, because he is relying on the formula rather than the physical interpretation.
While the Wigner rotation may appear frame dependent, all observers will agree the object has rotated, once it completes a full closed loop path and returns to its starting point and comes to rest again.
The order of the successive linear Lorentz boosts results in different rotations.
For ease of construction I had simplify some details. For example when separate impulses are applied to the far ends of the rod, the rod can not move instantaneously as whole and remain straight and would be observed to bend in some reference frames.
A gyroscope mounted inside the the red frame will not detect any rotation. This is easy to see in the left hand animation where the red square is parallel transported. This is slightly mysterious and I try to describe a physical interpretation below:


In the above animation a rod is initially moving inertially in the vertical y direction. In the rest frame of the rod, horizontal impulses in the x direction are applied simultaneously to the ends of the rod, but of course in this reference frame where the rod is moving, these impulse are not simultaneous. The rear B impulse occurs before the A impulse at the front and starts the rod rotating. The later A impulse merely stops the rotation continuing. The orange circle is a start signal from the centre, that is there to ensure the impulses are simultaneous in the rest frame of the rod. The dashed orange vectors represent information about the torque impulses travelling along the rod to the centre, where the flywheel of a gyroscope is located (the blue rectangle). These impulse torque signals both reach the flywheel at the same time and to the flywheel it appears as if the impulses were applied simultaneously in its rest frame, so the gyroscope 'feels' no torque and accelerates linearly.
I hope you now have a good 'feel' for what is happening physically and can apply the insights to your investigations.
For additional reference:
here is webpage that describes Thomas rotation in terms of parallel transport on the surface of a sphere and describes a neat "conical paper hat" visualisation.
Mathpages: "Boosts and Rotations"
